# Making a cell border exactly like Excel's fill handle?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, cell

I am trying to make a webpage that looks exactly like an Excel Spreadsheet. Instead of using other tools like images, I want to do it by using html and css only.

A screenshot of my local webpage:

[image: http://imgur.com/VZxiOnt]

But the problem is that I don't know how to put a square at bottom-right of the border of cell B2, so that it looks like a Fill Handle as in Excel.

Please help me. Table coding I have used is:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ExcelTableFormationCol {
                          width: 55px;
                          height: 20px;
                          text-align: center;
                          font-family: Arial Narrow;
                          font-size: 14px;
                         }

.ExcelTableFormationRow {
                          background-color: #EEEEEE;
                          text-align: center;
                          font-family: Calibri;
                          font-size: 16px;
                          height: 20px;
                         }

#LastRow td {
              border-bottom-width: 0px;
            }

.LastCol {
           border-right-width: 0px;
         }
</style>

<table border="" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;">
  <tr style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
    <td style="width: 25px;"></td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol">A</td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol" style="background-color: Gold;">B</td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol">C</td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol">D</td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol">E</td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol">F</td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol">G</td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol">H</td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol">I</td>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationCol" style="border-right-width: 0px;">J</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationRow">1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="LastCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationRow" style="background-color: Gold;">2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="border: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="LastCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationRow">3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="LastCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationRow">4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="LastCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationRow">5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="LastCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationRow">6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="LastCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationRow">7</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="LastCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationRow">8</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="LastCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="LastRow">
    <td class="ExcelTableFormationRow">9</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="LastCol"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to hack that up with the combination of black box with white borders along with absolute positioning after relative outer div.

Looks like this:

[image]

Full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/68KAZ/1/

HTML (for the cursor cell)

```
<td style="border: 3px solid black;">
  <div id="ExcelCursorOuter"><div id="ExcelCursor"></div></div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
 #ExcelCursorOuter {
   position: relative;
 }

 #ExcelCursor {
   position: absolute;
   top: 8px;
   right: -5px;
   background: #000;
   width: 5px;
   height: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   border-right: 0px;
   border-bottom: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Your coding does what i wanted. Though it will take some time for me to understand it in terms of how it works in CSS, but for now it worked.

Comment: But now there is another problem. I want to show cell B2 as some text as being enter in it, like formula. When i type an equal sign (=) for beginning a formula, the height of Row 2 increased and the Fill Handle gone down. It should in its place irrespective of cell content. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
`table
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}`